# external-secrets operator not using IRSA role

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have external-secrets operator v0.5.1 installed and working with a SecretStore for retrieve AWS parameter store. Also tried updating to V0.5.8

This is working fine with IRSA but if I try to create a external-secret for AWS secrets, with a new SecretStore, the SecretStore' status is Valid but the ExternalSecret that references this SecretStore got the following error: `SecretSyncedError`

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::12345678:assumed-role/eks-backend-role-pre/external-secrets-provider-aws is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: /backend/pre/PRE_PRIVPGPKEY because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action status code: 400,
```

Please, note the STS is trying to use `eks-backend-role-pre/external-secrets-provider-aws` which it doesn't exist. The role which exist is `eks-backend-role-pre` I'm not sure who is adding the suffix `external-secrets-provider-aws` which invalidate the role name.

Both SecretStore, the one dedicated to AWS Parameter Store and the other that is dedicated to gather from AWS Secrets has the same service account associated.

Why is working one External Secret and the other using the same service account don't?

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the policy.
As documentation shows, this is the correct way to declare a principal:

arn:${Partition}:secretsmanager:${Region}:${Account}:secret:${SecretId}

I have incorrect declared the principal:

```
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:1234567890:secret/backend/pre/*"
```

Correct:

```
        "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:1234567890:secret:/backend/pre/*"
```

In contrast to SSM Parameter store that you declare your principal                 `"arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:1234567890:parameter/backend/pre/*"`
, with SecretsManager you need to add a colon after the service `:secret:`